# Java - JComboBox remove highlight

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, jcombobox, jcomponent

currently I am working with some JComponents to build a little tool. While i was changing some things like the background-color it became visible that the combobox has some highlighting border. I already removed the border and changed all options for its apperance. Does someone know what this highlight is called or how it can be removed?

[Here you can see the slight blue/white highlight.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZd03.png)

Comment: Please add a picture of this highlight

Comment: I did add an Image. Hope that helps to resolve the problem :)

Comment: Please add what you've done so far with your code, and a picture which can shows us the result UI

Comment: Added Picture. The Code only creates a CoboBox and sets Border and Background to gray. That's all.

Comment: I need to see by which Swing components you used, please share your code that I could see it

Answer (score 0):

You could be talking about the renderer for your ComboBox.

The following link might help you out:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer

You can override the default implementation of your ComboBox to create your own custom version.

More specifically, check out the `setBackground` and `setForeground` parts.

Comment: I already use setBackground and setForeground. The problem is NOT the Background, Font nor Border. I've set them all. It still shows some highlight even tought its not selected. I added an Image.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found! 
The problem is the «shadow» color of the theme.
You can create a new class that will change the color set in the Ocean theme of Metal LAF.

```
import javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.OceanTheme;

public class NewTheme extends OceanTheme{
  public  ColorUIResource getControlShadow(){
    return new ColorUIResource(255,255,255);
 }

}
```

When it's done, you just have to set this new theme with those linee of code :

```
 UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel"); 
 MetalLookAndFeel.setCurrentTheme(new NewTheme());
```